# How to load csv file into SparkR on RStudio?

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

How do you load csv file into SparkR on RStudio? Below are the steps I had to perform to run SparkR on RStudio. I have used read.df to read .csv not sure how else to write this. Not sure if this step is considered to create RDDs.

```
#Set sys environment variables
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "C:/Users/Desktop/spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6")
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib"), .libPaths()))

#Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages" "com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3" "sparkr-shell"')

#Load libraries
library(SparkR)
library(magrittr)

sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")
sc <- sparkR.init()
sc <- sparkR.init(sparkPackages="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.0.3")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

data <- read.df(sqlContext, "C:/Users/Desktop/DataSets/hello_world.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

I am getting error:

```
Error in writeJobj(con, object) : invalid jobj 1
```

Answer (score 3):

**Spark 2.0.0+**:

You can use csv data source:

```
loadDF(sqlContext, path="some_path", source="csv", header="true")
```

without loading `spark-csv`.

**Original answer**:

As far as I can tell you're using a wrong version of `spark-csv`. Pre-built versions of Spark are using Scala 2.10, but you're using Spark CSV for Scala 2.11. Try this instead:

```
sc <- sparkR.init(sparkPackages="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0")
```

Comment: I tried new spark-csv from above. Now I when I run data <- read.df, I get this error: Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE.

Comment: Could you provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: Are you referring to R console outputs?

Comment: Yep, there should be much more than `Error: returnStatus == 0`

Comment: 'Error: returnStatus == 0 is not TRUE' is only error I got when I was running 'read.df'.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you copy input file to the working directory and use a relative path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91039/discussion-between-zero323-and-sharp).

Comment: sc <- sparkR.init(sparkPackages="com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3") did it for me (and starting sparkR console like this:

sparkR --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3)

Answer (score 1):

I successfully solve this issue by providing the commons-csv-1.2.jar together with the spark-csv package.

Apparently, spark-csv uses commons-csv but is not package with it.

Using the following SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS solved the issue (I use --jars rather than --packages).

```
Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--jars" "/usr/lib/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-csv_2.11-1.2.0.jar,/usr/lib/spark-1.5.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/commons-csv-1.2.jar" "sparkr-shell"')
```

In fact, the rather obscure error

```
Error in writeJobj(con, object) : invalid jobj 1
```

Is more clear using the R shell directly instead from R Studio and clearly state

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat
```

The needed commons-csv jar can be found here : https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/download_csv.cgi

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate everyone's input and solutions!!! I figured out another way to load .csv file into SparkR RStudio. Here it is:

```
#set sc
sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local")
sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

#load .csv 
patients <- read.csv("C:/...") #Insert your .csv file path

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, patients)
df
head(df)
str(df)
```

Comment: Your solution works, but is not scalable: when your patients set does not fit into memory, you won't be able to load in R and convert in to SparkR, but you should still be able to load it directly to SparkR.

Comment: Good point. I did run into this. However, with the user's answers below, I am getting errors. Trying to look how I can load the data directly into SparkR.

Comment: The Sys.setenv('SPARKR_SUBMIT_ARGS'='"--packages"... works fine for me.