# Sparkr Read/Write with HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, sparkr

I am trying to figure out how to read and write arbitrary files to/from HDFS in SparkR.

Set up is:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = T)
MASTER <- args[1]
SPARK_HOME <- args[2]
INPATH <- 'hdfs/path/to/read/or/load/from'
OUTPATH <- 'hdfs/path/to/write/save/to'

Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = SPARK_HOME) 
.libPaths(c(file.path(Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME'), 'R', 'lib'), .libPaths())
library(SparkR)

sparkR.session(master = MASTER)

# How to load RData?
load(paste(INPATH, rObjects.RData, sep = '')

# How to read data?
dat <- read.csv(paste(INPATH, datafile.csv, sep = '')

# Perform operations.....

# How to write?
write.csv(dat, paste(OUTPATH, outdata.csv, sep = '')
```

I know that these procedures can be done with a shell script, or similar system calls within R, e.g.:

```
system('hadoop fs -copyToLocal ...')
```

but, I am intentionally trying to avoid these solutions.

Spark v. 2.0.1

R v. 3.3.2

*Edit:*
Comment below notes this is a possible duplicate-- that question deals more specifically with reading csvs (part of my question), but still unclear how to load .RData or read/write files more generally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load csv file into SparkR on RStudio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873434/how-to-load-csv-file-into-sparkr-on-rstudio)

Comment: Thanks. That addresses a more specific question about how to load a csv as a data.frame (part of my question), but still unclear how to load .RData and write to HDFS

Comment: Spark has no suitable readers and SparkR doesn't interact with file system directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read & write data frame in SparkR use these

```
sdf <- read.df(csvPath, "csv", header = "true", inferSchema = "true", na.strings = "NA")
write.df(people, path = "people. csv", source = "csv", mode = "overwrite")
```

To work with rdd use these

```
rdd <- SparkR:::textFile(sc = sc,path = "path",minPartitions = 4)
SparkR:::saveAsTextFile(X,"path")
```

Databricks has a good package for working with csv files in SparkR, [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#r-api)

Comment: Thanks for your input, Manikanta.  Still trying to figure out how to load .RData files from HDFS